# Que signifie « dans la durée » ?

Tags: sens

Je lisais cet [article](http://www.famillechretienne.fr/politique-societe/societe/la-manif-pour-tous-maintient-la-pression-205593), où j'ai trouvé la phrase suivante:

> Une telle mobilisation dans la durée ne peut que susciter le respect.

Que signifie « *dans la durée* » dans ce cas-là?

Comment: Je suggère: "dans ce cas-là ?" à la place de "à ce cas-lá?", "cet article", et peut-être "où je trouve" à la place de "quand la je trouve"

Comment: Merci Laurent ;)

Comment: Dans le titre, "à" a un accent grave également

Comment: @LaurentDuval vous avez raison. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

L'expression « dans la durée » désigne une action ou un état qui dure longtemps. C'est quelque chose qui compte pour le long terme. Dans certains cas les deux expressions sont synonymes ; par exemple « une solution dans la durée » et « une solution à long terme » sont deux manières de dire « une solution qui continuera d'être valable pendant longtemps ».

Si des gens manifestent une fois, c'est une mobilisation ponctuelle. Si une manifestation est organisée chaque semaine pendant plusieurs mois, c'est une mobilisation dans la durée. Ici on ne dirait pas « une mobilisation à long terme » parce que « à long terme » part du principe que la mobilisation continuera pendant longtemps quoi qu'il arrive, alors que « dans la durée » convient si la mobilisation peut s'arrêter bientôt si la revendication est satisfaite.

Comment: @Faʁdɔʃɔtɔmatabaʁwɛt Il n'y a pas de verbe, même sous-entendu, donc ce n'est pas une relative. Il y a bien un rapport d'intériorité dans le temps : « dans la durée », ce qui est inhabituel est que dans cette expression, l'important n'est pas ce rapport d'intériorité mais le fait que la durée en question est entièrement couverte. Il serait peut-être plus logique de dire « dans toute une durée » ou « sur une longue durée », mais « dans la durée » (ou quelquefois « dans la longue durée ») est l'expression idiomatique.

Comment: Merci Gilles ;)

Comment: Instead of “dans la durée” being used here as an adjective in its “long-term” sense to modify “mobilisation", couldn’t it alternatively be seen as an adverb in its “over time/in the long run” sense to modify “ne peut que susciter”? “Mobilisation" already has an adj. (“telle”) & if “telle” refers to the mobilization's nature (including its “non-ponctuelle” one [though I’m not sure the cited article makes it clear that the single event on Oct.16 was other than a “ponctuelle” one]), so couldn't having “dans la durée” modify the noun (instead of the verb) make the sentence unnecessarily redundant?

Comment: @PapaPoule “Dans la durée” is a *complément circonstanciel*, so I think it attaches to the sentence as a whole rather than to a noun clause, but I'm not sure about that. I think you should ask that as a new question, about grammar. The meaning is perfectly clear to any native speaker but how to analyze this grammatically isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Dans la durée means "in the long run" in English

Comment: Hi! Welcome to French Language and thanks for your contribution. Could you flesh out your answer e.g. by adding references or an explanation or definition of this idiom? As is it is a bit terse and does not add a lot of value over Gilles' answer. You can also have a look at [the help](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) to learn more about our philosophy or join us in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1098/chez-cosette)