# L'expression « dans la durée » : analyse, fonction de la préposition, forme du complément ?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, indications-de-temps

Dans une autre [question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/22457), on a traité du sens de l'expression « dans la durée ». On s'intéresse ici à l'analyse grammaticale et à l'emploi de la préposition [*dans*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dans/1) dans l'expression. À défaut de pouvoir reproduire des [phrases](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dans%20la%20dur%C3%A9e&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdans%20la%20dur%C3%A9e%3B%2Cc0) dont on est certain que l'emploi est celui dont on traite, on reproduit la phrase présentée dans l'autre question :

> Une telle mobilisation *dans la durée* ne peut que susciter le respect.

---

- Quelle est la nature et la fonction grammaticale de *dans la durée* dans la phrase ; est-ce la *mobilisation dans la durée* ou l'expression
  s'applique-t-elle à un autre niveau ?
- La préposition *dans* reste-t-elle analysable et si oui, à laquelle
  de ses fonctions son emploi se rattache-t-il ; y a-t-il d'autres
  prépositions usuelles équivalentes/complémentaires dans ce contexte ?
- Y a-t-il une nuance de sens ou autre entre la mobilisation *dans la
  durée/qui perdure, se prolonge/soutenue* (soit l'expression, la
  proposition relative, et l'épithète en contexte) ; y a-t-il un lien à faire avec des emplois de *dans le [temps](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/temps)*, voire *dans l'[espace](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/espace)* ?
- Peut-on présenter d'autres exemples qui mettent en valeur l'expression *dans la durée* ?

Answer (score 1):

Je ne suis pas sur de comprendre ce qui te pose problème.

> Une telle mobilisation dans la durée <sub>ne peut que susciter le respect.</sub>

Pourrait être reformulée :

> Une mobilisation durant une période de temps d'une telle importance <sub>ne peut que susciter le respect.</sub>

Je pense que ça peut t'aider à identifier les fonctions grammaticales.

- *dans la durée* 
  **nature** : préposition / déterminant / nom commun 
  **fonction** : complément du nom "mobilisation"
- on indique ici un repère dans l'espace temps : s'étalant le long de cette *durée*. 
  Je ne vois pas d'autres prépositions conservant le sens exact dans le contexte.
- Je ne comprends pas quelle nuance tu veux mettre en relief, donne des exemples plus complet. 
  *nom commun* + dans + *nom représentant une mesure d'espace [temps]* aura toujours le sens de lier le *nom* complémenté avec cette *mesure d'espace [temps]*. 
  Ici on souligne que **la mobilisation s'inscrit dans la durée**.
- Enfin, je te propose [ce lien](http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/traduction/dans+la+dur%C3%A9e.html) avec pas mal d'exemple (+la traduction, mais ce n'est pas l'intérêt ici)

Je ne suis pas grammairien dans l'âme alors n'hésite pas à critiquer pour qu'on puisse avancer sur ta question.

Comment: Merci ! Ouais, je vais réfléchir à ça. On dit _aura toujours le sens de lier_ mais je ne vois pas objectivement pourquoi on affirme ça. Avec le verbe pron./reflé. _s'inscrire_, le _dans_ ne me pose plus de difficulté. D'une certaine manière je me demande si c'est un peu comme un latinisme avec en/_in_ qui se cache en dessous etc.

Comment: @exilanceéglisée *premier GN* + `dans = dedans = à l'intérieur de` + *second GN d'espace*  - on dit bien que les deux sont liés par une forme de contenance?